# Why do I get error "was not declared in this scope"

Tags: c++, oop, strcpy, strlen

This is a part of my code where I get two errors:

```
void Person::setName(char* n) {
    Name = new char[strlen(n) + 1];
    strcpy(Name, n);
}
```

```
main.cpp:217:26: error: ‘strlen’ was not declared in this scope
  Name = new char[strlen(n) + 1];
main.cpp:218:16: error: ‘strcpy’ was not declared in this scope
  strcpy(Name, n);
```

I am using online C++ compiler.

Comment: Have you `#include <cstring>` or `#include <string.h>`?

Comment: I have @LukaKostic

Comment: try std::strlen and std::strcpy

Comment: It's time to learn about and use `std::string`. Using `new` on `char` is missing the point of C++.

Comment: @HANA `strlen()` and `strcpy()` are in `<string.h>`, while `std::strlen()` and `std::strcpy()` are in `<cstring>`. Make sure you are not mismatching them.

Comment: also Name needs a datatype. Unless it's global or something or the name of the member variable, in which case should probably be prepended with an m. like mName